# Linked lists, removeFirst() not working

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have this function that my g++ doesn't seem to like, and I have no idea why.

I wrote it so it could be buggy, but I can't see the error indicated by the compiler.

I paste in here the relevant parts.

```
// STRUCT
struct node {
  int data;
  node * next;
};

// PROTOTYPE
void removeFirst( node ** root );

// DEFINITION
void removeFirst( node ** root ) {
    node * tmp = *root
    *root = tmp->next; // is equivalent to (*root)->next
}

linkedLists.cpp:89:2: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('node *' and 'node **')
        *root = tmp->next;
        ^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Note: I don't actually need to delete tmp, because it's just a plain `node *`.

Comment: If you have allocated the node, then yes you need to delete it or you will have a memory leak.

Comment: it was actually a node (so I have to free it) and I had no idea because I rewrote the whole class a little time ago changing this aspect... thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed `;` after the first assignment. Thus, compiler read your function like

```
node *tmp = *root * root ...
```

and this causes the error. (Hint: if you cannot get a compiler error, always look one line backwards.)

Also, consider freeing memory (`tmp`) after deleting the first node, otherwise you get a memory leak. This depends on how you allocate nodes: if you `new` them, then use `delete tmp`; if you `malloc` them, use `free(tmp)`. Well, if you do not allocate memory per each node (e.g. you allocate a whole array of nodes and then use them) then you shouldn't deallocate `tmp`, but you might want to mark the node as free (depends on how you manage the array of nodes).

Comment: I can't believe I'm still committing this dumb mistakes. Thank you for relieving my headache! I'll sign this as the accepted answer as soon as I can. Should I delete this question then?

Comment: It's up to you. Deleting the question will take off all the brownie points from me though :)